# Oracle - Timestamp

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

When importing columns of type "Timestamp" to an Oracle DB:

```
Import tbl:
02.09.13 00:00:00
```

After importing:

```
Oracle tbl:
02.09.13 08:23:44,000000000
```

In the Oracle tbl the type is also "Timestamp".
How can I remove the ",000000000"?

Comment: You cannot remove it. In timestamp datatype the microseconds part is added. If you really want to modify it change the datatype. But its not advisable.

Comment: The `000000000` you see is because timestamp data type stores the fraction of a second upto 10 decimal places. Also, it is not `02.09.13 08:23:44,000000000`, it is `02.09.13 08:23:44.000000000`. No worries, just ignore this as what you are seeing is just a character conversion of the timestamp. You can remove the `000000000` by using `TO_CHAR(column_name, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`.

Comment: The OP isn't seeing a character conversion of the timestamp @Rachcha; they're just using a DB/session where the NLS_TERRITORY is set to one that uses a comma there in the default date format, for instance most of Europe.

Comment: Oh, that's an important point. Thanks, Ben!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TIMESTAMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00203) datatype includes fractional seconds; there is no way to remove them within the database whilst maintaining the datatype. If you don't want fractional seconds then put the date into a DATE column.

It shouldn't matter whether the fractional seconds are stored or not. When selecting from the database into anything other than another date datatype you should format the date as required by the client displaying it. The normal method of doing this would be by using the function [`TO_CHAR()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions188.htm#SQLRF06129); for instance:

```
select to_char(column_name, 'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss') from table_name
```

You can also do this at a session level by [changing your NLS settings](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_globalization.htm#CACIFHHI).

---

Unrelated to your question, but to address the comment on a comma being part of your timestamp; the default date format is determined by [NLS_TERRITORY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams146.htm#REFRN10128). A comma is a perfectly valid character to have here. Altering the NLS_TERRITORY, for example to France, it will appear as part of the [NLS_DATE_FORMAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams137.htm#i1129826):

```
SQL>  alter session set nls_territory = 'FRANCE';

Session altered.

SQL> select systimestamp from dual
  2  ;

SYSTIMESTAMP
------------------------------------------------------------
18/09/13 13:09:54,418387 +01:00
```